# node js .Cannot pass a mongodb query result to a jade view

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have this code

```
exports.index = function (req, res) {
res.render('product/index.jade', {
    products: db.products.find().toArray(function (err, prods) {
        if (!err)
            return prods;
        return [];
    })
});
```

};

What I'm trying to do here is pass the query result to a jade view which expects a parameter named "products".
I ve tried a lot of combinations but neither of them works (right now i'm getting "cannot read proprty lenght....").
I know it must be a rookie mistake, but i cannot figure it out, any help will be apreciated!

PS: I'm using express and mongodb. And yes, the products collection does contain products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

toArray doesn't actually return a value. Instead, the callback function gets called with the products as a parameter once the lookup is done. this is due to node's async I/O nature.

Your code should probably look something like this

```
exports.index = function (req, res) {
    db.products.find().toArray(function (err, prods) {
        if (!err)
            res.render('product/index.jade', {products: prods});
        else
            res.render('product/index.jade', {products: []});
    });
});
```

Comment: It's the most common rookie mistake, io time is represented as function nesting in node.js, which takes some getting used to.